# Printing all primes recursively given a number

Tags: java, recursion

Can we recursively print all prime numbers below a given number? For example if printPrimes(10) is called, it should print 2,3,5,7.  I can check if a single number is prime recursively and iterate over 'n' one by one. But am wondering If a purely recursive solution is possible.

Comment: If the answer(s) here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerers and for other users of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already have a function that checks if a single number is prime ? Then sure

```
public void printNPrimes(int start, int n){
    if (start == n)
        return;
    if (isPrime(start))
        System.out.print(start);

    printNprimes(start + 1 , n );
}
```

call this function with printNprimes(0 , n); n being the number you wanted to go up to

Comment: Why do you need to have two arguments to the recursive method? You can just do it by one argument, initially send `n` and reduce it in every subsequent recursive call till it reaches 1, which is your terminating condition for your recursion. This will make your API more clean, as the user will not have to figure out what to pass as the first and the second argument.

Comment: @OleV.V. Done. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @LavishKothari that's true, but I guess this way you can specify a range

Answer (score 1):

Posting one of my comments as an answer:
You can just do it by a recursive method that takes one argument, initially send n and reduce it in every subsequent recursive call till it reaches 1, which is your terminating condition for your recursion. This will make your API more clean

The following is the code in Java:

```
public void printPrimesBelow(int n) {
    if(n > 1) {
        if(isPrime(n)) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        printPrimesBelow(n-1); // recurse over n-1
    }
}
```

A minor edit:

If you place the recursive call above the `if` statement, then the order of the primes in which they are printed will be increasing.

Comment: It throws "Stackoverflow error" for n=100000, but I also implemented isPrime with recursion too. Maybe using 2 recursions with 2 functions creates this error.